# How to get vaadin-grid to fill the page

Tags: polymer, vaadin

I am working with the vaadin-grid element (the polymer web component, not the java grid). I see that I can set the number of rows displayed on the grid via the `visible-rows` attribute. But I can't find a way to get the grid to take up all the available space, i.e. to dynamically set the rows to just what is need to fill the page. The documentation implies this is possible. And the [demo expenses app](https://demo.vaadin.com/expense-manager/) seems to do this as well, though I can't figure out where.

Here is a very simple example that will display 10 rows always, no matter page size.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-elements/latest/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-elements/latest/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>
<vaadin-grid>
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col>
            <col>
            <col>
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</vaadin-grid>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using `visible-rows` attribute, you can use plain CSS to set the `height` property directly.

You can also use `flex` like done in the Expense Manager demo.

I've modified your code a bit to give an example how you can use `flex` property.

```
   <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-elements/latest/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-elements/latest/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html" rel="import">
</head>

    <body style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <div id="content" style="flex: 1">
      Some Content Here
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="flex: 3; display: flex">
    <vaadin-grid style="flex: 1">
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Progress</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Project A</td><td>10000</td><td>0.8</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </vaadin-grid>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

You can try it live on jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/kigonu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: In your jsbin example, I still just see 10 rows displayed and it doesn't take all the available vertical space.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested that with Chrome 49.

Comment: I was using Firefox. You're right, your example works with Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Firefox might need some prefixed CSS rules for flex.